# Oldest monument in Rome

Tags: factoids, landmarks, rome

I know this question might seem a bit weird, but this is really difficult to find an answer to me.

Rome is well known to be one of the city in the world which has the biggest quantity of ancient monuments/ruins. 
It is NOT of course the city where there is the OLDEST monument/ruin in the world. Probably there is some small city in the world where there are pre-hystorical ruins or wall-paintings.

But, within the city of Rome (inside the big round highway called "Grande Raccordo Anulare") which is the oldest monument or ruin which is possible to watch for a tourist?

Comment: A lot of the oldest stuff in Italy is actually in Sardinia. I don't know if it's the oldest in Rome, but the Colloseum does appear on a lot of lists as one of the oldest structures.  Can't confirm for sure that it's the oldest in Rome, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [historvius.com](http://www.historvius.com/search/?country=IT&resort=rome&resortId=&cmd=1&type=destinationSearch), among the oldest structures you can visit are the [Mamertine Prison](http://www.historvius.com/mamertine-prison-727/), dating back to the 7th century BC, as well as the [Temple of Vesta (wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Vesta) on the [Forum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monuments_of_the_Roman_Forum), which dates from the same period.